# Alpha blending never reaches opaque color in HTML Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

### Background

I am implementing an animation which requires trails behind moving objects based on their speed. The easiest way [which people used for long time](https://codepen.io/gbnikolov/pen/VLLgRW) is to draw the object and then periodically `fillRect()` the scene with background color using small alpha values (~5%).

### Problem

However, the background where particles were long time ago **never reaches its original color**:
[image: particles]

It seems like true opaque color is never reached. In every browser I tested (FF, Chrome, Safari) it stops at `rgba(12,0,0,1)`:

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
const count = document.getElementById('count');
const color = document.getElementById('color');

ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(255,0,0)';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);

var counter = 0;
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.04)';
window.setInterval(() => {
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,100,100);
  count.textContent = ++counter;
  const d = ctx.getImageData(50, 50, 1, 1).data;
  color.textContent = `${d[0]}, ${d[1]}, ${d[2]}, ${d[3] / 255}`;
}, 50);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas><br/>
Count: <span id="count">?</span><br/>
rgba(): <span id="color">?</span>
```

### Solution?

This problem seems to be described as [far back as 2011](http://rectangleworld.com/blog/archives/214) with no solutions (pixel manipulation causes an unacceptable CPU usage).

- Am I missing something?
- Is this an **expected** behavior as it's so consistent across all browsers?
- Is there any clever way around that except setting the background to non-black?

Comment: Yes it's expected, 1 × 0.5 -> 0.5 ; 0.5 × 0.5 -> 0.25 ; 0.25 x 0.5 -> 0.125 ; ... continue like that until you reach 25 zeroes after the dot and it would still not be `0`.

Comment: any work arounds? they should have a blend mode for that.